# How can I detect when the official YouTube page's view/content changes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, youtube, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a WebExtension for YouTube which should perform a set of actions once a watch/video page is reached, however, as the modern YouTube website is a single-page application, my content script is not run every time the content changes.

My initial instinct was to look up a way of detecting when the browser URL changes, and while I did find a such feature (listening for hashchange), it only seems to apply when the fragment part (everything past the #) of the URL changes, which is not the case on YouTube.

How can I detect when the content changes?

Comment: Checkout mutation observer(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). This is probably what you want.

Comment: @GanapatiVS this is brilliant! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout mutation observer(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). This is probably what you want.